# Finding parent node of parsed XML in Objective-C

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I'm parsing through a bunch of XML and I'm trying to find if a node is inside / parent of another node before I process it. Is there a way of knowing what the parent of a niode is?

Comment: What classes/framework are you using to parse the XML?

Comment: NSXMLParserDelegate parser:didStartElement:namespaceURI:qualifiedName:attributes: 
parser:didEndElement:namespaceURI:qualifiedName: parser:foundCharacters:

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Record the parent node yourself. You're using an event-based parser. It very deliberately keeps track of nothing except what is necessary to ensure the document is well-formed. If you need to know the parent node, record each node in a stack in didStartElement and then pop off the node in didEndElement.

Comment: thanks yeh, so just used a few BOOL's to see what was where and when